# Why the channel is not working?

Tags: go

I am studying ‘Go Concurrency Pattern' from https://talks.golang.org/2012/concurrency.slide#25'

**Question**:

1. How the channel share variable from it's outside ? In this case **i** has been shared.
   Variable at point A and point B seems to have some special relation ? What is it ?
2. What does it means for ?

   for i := 0; ; i++

Main code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func boring(msg string) <-chan string { // Returns receive-only channel of strings.

    c := make(chan string)
    go func() { // We launch the goroutine from inside the function.
        for i := 0; ; i++ {           // <--------- point B
            c <- fmt.Sprintf("%s %d", msg, i)

            time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(1e3)) * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }()
    return c // Return the channel to the caller.
}

func main() {
    c := boring("boring!") // Function returning a channel.
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {               // <--------- point A
        fmt.Printf("You say: %q\n", <-c)
    }
    fmt.Println("You're boring; I'm leaving.")
}
```

output:

```
You say: "boring! 0"
You say: "boring! 1"
You say: "boring! 2"
You say: "boring! 3"
You say: "boring! 4"
You're boring; I'm leaving.
Program exited.
```

Comment: how exactly are you running this? Go is not a scripting language, you know. you need to compile the program and run it with `go run`. Also, it can't be `package a1` if you're going to run it, it has to be `package main`

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer I fixed the problem by changing the package name. Thanks. But don't know how it works...

Comment: First: Channels do _not_ lead to magical connection of variables or sharing of variables. Actually channels have *nothing* to do with variables. What channels do is: They take *values* which you stuff into the channel and spit the same value out at the other end. Often these values come from variables and often these variables have the same (or a similar) name. Second: The `for` you  loop you mention works like in C. Have a look at the tour or the language spec for this type of basic questions.

Comment: @Volker I think I got the answer. At point B, goroutine infinitely stuff in int values, 1...n. Then point A, talk them out one by one! But still not quite confident about the order of 'blocking'...Neither sure of how infinity loop works. I mean is it lazy ?

Comment: Almost. Point B is just a the for loop; increasing integer values are stuffed into the channel at `c <- ...`. The for loop is not "lazy" (whatever that means). It is just an endless for loop which increments `i` on each turn. Sending and receiving from the channel block, this has nothing to do with the for loop. Did you take the whole Go Tour?

Answer (score 0):

The `for (i := 0; ; i++) { }` creates an index the increments forever.

When you `make(chan string )` you've created a read/write channel. You also reference the channel inside the go function and pass it out as the return value. Go does an analysis of how variables are used called "escape analysis" and chooses whether to make the channel on the heap or on the stack, in your case on the heap so that when the function creating the channel exits the channel doesn't get deallocated.